# Android ImageView setImageBitmap or draw bitmap in canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, ondraw

I have 40 instances of my custom ImageView (added programmatically to my layout) that eval their size dinamically (according to display size in pixel). 
Is it better to call myCustomView.setImageBitmap or override onDraw and draw bitmap in canvas?
All of these views can only be clicked, dragged and/or dropped; no other operations are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw complex things and make complex Views, for example, image and text below, or come circle with image in it, you must use onDraw.
But if you want just to display one image, you could go for setImageBitmap, because it is much easier to do.
So the answer is: solution depends on your needs and drawing complexity.

Comment: Thanks @vanste25 . I would understand if drawing bitmap is cheaper than setImageBitmap in terms of memory usage. setImageBitmap (even using UniversalImageLoader) leads many OutOfMemoryError, so I'm wondering if drawing bitmaps is a "lighter" operation.

Comment: That depends how often you call invalidate. If you do it many times, then the performance will suffer. Also, do not allocate memory during onDraw execution. 
I think that you should use setImageBitmap because it is optimized for showing bitmap. That is its natural behavior.

Comment: And what about setImageBitmap? Does it lead to OutOfMemoryError too?

Comment: yes it does. I have 25 different activities (all children of MyParentActivity), that must show about 40 imageviews, but they change size according to activity layout. When I open another activity I have to show 40 imageview having different size of previous. After switching about 5/6 activities I get OOM. I load scaledBitmap, kept them in a static LruCache and then I setImageBitmap() passing right scaled. When I switch activity I evictAll Bitmaps and reload scaled version (according to actual layout specs).